# Does Benford's Law Actually Work?

Tags: r, probability, distributions, uniform-distribution, logarithm

Recently, I have been reading about Benford's Law :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law

[image]

This law supposedly states that naturally occurring numbers are more likely to start with the number "1" (roughly 30% of the time), followed by "2" (17% of the time) - in decreasing order, all the way until "9". This law is famously said to able to detect "manipulated and fraudulent" data.

I started looking at some of the mathematical background behind this law and came across the following (https://plus.maths.org/content/looking-out-number-one):

- Take some number - extract the leading digit of this number. Call this leading digit "x"
- Now, define "y" as y = log(x)
- If "y" has a  uniform distribution between (0,1), then "x" will have a scale invariant distribution between (1,10).
- Thus, the probability of the leading digit starting with "1" can be represented as the "probability of x greater than equal to 1 and less than 2".
- This probability is equal to : integral(uniform distribution) over (0, log2) .
- If you evaluate this integral, this integral is roughly equal to 0.301
- You can repeat this integral over different ranges to find out the probability of a number starting with some leading digit (e.g.  probability of a number starting with 2 is the integral(uniform distribution) over (log2, log3))

I even attempted to check Benford's Law using World Population Data and the R programming language:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

world_data <- read_csv("https://population.un.org/wpp/Download/Files/1_Indicators%20(Standard)/CSV_FILES/WPP2019_TotalPopulationBySex.csv")


 head(world_data)

  LocID    Location VarID Variant Time MidPeriod  PopMale PopFemale PopTotal PopDensity
1     4 Afghanistan     2  Medium 1950    1950.5 4099.243  3652.874 7752.117     11.874
2     4 Afghanistan     2  Medium 1951    1951.5 4134.756  3705.395 7840.151     12.009
3     4 Afghanistan     2  Medium 1952    1952.5 4174.450  3761.546 7935.996     12.156
4     4 Afghanistan     2  Medium 1953    1953.5 4218.336  3821.348 8039.684     12.315
5     4 Afghanistan     2  Medium 1954    1954.5 4266.484  3884.832 8151.316     12.486
6     4 Afghanistan     2  Medium 1955    1955.5 4318.945  3952.047 8270.992     12.669


world_data$PopMale = as.numeric(substr(world_data$PopMale,1,1))
world_data$PopFemale = as.numeric(substr(world_data$PopFemale,1,1))
world_data$PopTotal = as.numeric(substr(world_data$PopTotal,1,1))
world_data$PopDensity = as.numeric(substr(world_data$PopDensity,1,1))


g1 = ggplot(world_data, aes(x=PopMale)) + geom_histogram() +    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10,1)) + ggtitle("Male Population") 
g2 = ggplot(world_data, aes(x=PopFemale)) + geom_histogram() +  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10,1)) +  ggtitle("Female Population")
g3 = ggplot(world_data, aes(x=PopTotal)) + geom_histogram() +  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10,1)) + ggtitle("Total Population")
g4 = ggplot(world_data, aes(x=PopDensity)) + geom_histogram()+  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10,1)) + ggtitle("Population Density")


plot_row = plot_grid(g1, g2, g3, g4)

# now add the title
title <- ggdraw() + 
  draw_label(
    "World Population: Does Benford's Law Exist?",
    fontface = 'bold',
    x = 0,
    hjust = 0
  ) +
  theme(
    # add margin on the left of the drawing canvas,
    # so title is aligned with left edge of first plot
    plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 7)
  )
plot_grid(
  title, plot_row,
  ncol = 1,
  # rel_heights values control vertical title margins
  rel_heights = c(0.1, 1)
)
```

[image]

Interestingly enough, the above histograms seem to roughly follow Benford's Law - suggesting that the World Population Data has not been manipulated.

**My Question:** Does Benford's Law still apply if "y" does not have a Uniform Distribution?

For instance, I took one of the columns from the World Population Data:

```
 hist(as.numeric(log(world_data$PopMale)))
hist(as.numeric(log(world_data$PopFemale)))
hist(as.numeric(log(world_data$PopDensity)))
hist(as.numeric(log(world_data$PopTotal)))
```

None of these plots of the transformed variables seem to follow a uniform distribution - but the the original plots still seem to follow Benford's Law.

Can someone please explain this? **How important is it for "y" to follow a Uniform Distribution for Benford's Law to work?**

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Benford's Law is a mathematical model that fits some datasets and not others. It is true under its assumptions, and violations of Benford's Law in real-world data indicates that one or more of those assumptions do not hold.

Comment: You haven't fully stated the law.  It requires that the data you are examining span several orders of magnitude--and even then it's not really a "law" in the sense of, say, physical theory: at best it can be called a "likely regularity."